# Css selector for second child elements

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

The html looks like this:

```
<ul class="plotAreaCol">
<li>
  39
    <em> dgr</em>
</li>
<li class="light" title="Tomtarea">
   3 970
     <em> m²</em>
 </li>
</ul>
```

And I want a css selector for BOTH 'em' elements

Comment: Have you tried *anything*?

Answer (score 0):

You should use this I think

```
ul.plotAreaCol li em
```

or this

```
ul.plotAreaCol em
```

or this

```
.plotAreaCol em
```

Or something similar.